# Artdarek oauth-4-laravel / Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib: Posting LinkedIn Share API not working

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I am using https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel for my latest project. I was able to implement LinkedIn [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) using this, but the posting share is not working. Here is my code:

```
$params['content'] ='
<share>
<comment>Check out the LinkedIn Share API!</comment>
<content>
    <title>LinkedIn Developers Documentation On Using the Share API</title><description>Leverage the Share API to maximize engagement on user-generated content on LinkedIn</description>
    <submitted-url>https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api</submitted-url>
    <submitted-image-url>http://m3.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/124/1a6/089a29a.png</submitted-image-url>
</content>
<visibility>
    <code>connections-only</code>
</visibility>
</share>';

$extraHeaders = array(
    'Content-type' =>  'application/xml',
);
$status = json_decode($linkedinService->request('people/~/shares?format=json', 'POST',
                      $params, $extraHeaders ));
```

But the posting is not working. But I can post using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), so I think my access_token is OK. Here is my cURL code

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/{$post->linkedInGroupAccount->linkedin_id}/posts?format=json&oauth2_access_token={$post->linkedInGroupAccount->access_token}");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
$header[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8';
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$post->msg = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle)
```

Why is the $linkedinService->request() not working?

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but did you ever solve this? If yes, how?

Comment: No, Could not figure the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code
you xml content should like this

```
$XML = "<share>
        <comment>This is a comment</comment>
        <content>
        <title>This is the title</title>
        <submitted-url>http://yourapp.dev</submitted-url>
        <submitted-image-url>http://yourapp.dev/image.jpg</submitted-image-url>
        <description>#riseofthetiger</description>
        </content>
        <visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility>
        </share>";
```

and your header should like this

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/xml',
            'x-li-format' => 'xml',
        );
```

then request like this

```
$result = json_decode( $linkedin->request('/people/~/shares?format=json', 'POST', $XML, $headers),true );
```

hope that worked

Comment: i do not think the xml spacing is the issue. Because I can post with the same xml using cURL.